# Quasi Newton taking very small steps

Tags: newton-method, quasi-newton

I have implemented a Quasi-Newton method based on the Hessian approximation. I am noticing that the algorithm takes too many iterations to converge, even though it does converge. What I am not able to understand is the really small step size ($l_{\infty} \text{norm} \le 10^{-5}$) for many of these iterations. The problem is ill-conditioned and I read that Quasi-Newton can degenerate to steepest descent for ill-conditioned problems. Is that what is happening? If so, is there any intuition about the step size being so small? I have tried the damping modification given in section 18.3 from Nocedal and Wright. However, it is not improving the step length, since, the damping criterion itself becomes very small. Is there some other principled way to ensure larger step size? Will larger step size help with faster convergence?

Comment: There are many "quasi-Newton" methods. Which one are you using?

Comment: I have implemented limited memory BFGS. I am using the Hessian approximation formulation, not the approximation of the Hessian inverse.

Comment: It is possible that full NR takes small steps when approaching a critical point of multiplicity more than one.  Perhaps the Hessian approximation is singular, or nearly so.

Comment: The problem is supposed to have an unique minimizer. Since, the problem is strictly convex. Yes, the Hessian approximation can be singular. It is only positive semidefinite away from the optimum. I am working under a trust region framework (by adding a Levenberg-Marquardt like damping matrix). But I see the damping parameter going to zero in the first few iterations (which is another unexpected behavior) and after that the algorithm proceeds as a plain Quasi-Newton method.

Comment: @hardmath I am wondering whether a singular Hessian approximation will lead to a huge step, instead of a very small step.

Comment: What is the problem? How long is you L-BFGS memory?  Keep in mind that L-BFGS approximates the inverse hessian as a low-rank modification to a multiple of the identity; you will get slow convergence if this approximation is poor in directions that matter.

Comment: @tmyklebu the problem is very, very small steps as described in the question. This is happening close to the optimum.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  What function are you trying to minimise, how did you implement it and its gradient, and what parameter did you use for L-BFGS?  Tons of different things can go wrong here.

Comment: The function is a problem in computer vision. It can have between 1 million to 3 million variables. Its hessian is only positive semidefinite away from the optimum. I am calculating the gradient exactly. I am having a memory of 10 for the time being.

Comment: OK.  So I've successfully run L-BFGS with rather shorter memory (4) on problems that fit the description I've gotten out of you so far.  Either you are doing something wrong---and there are a million ways to go wrong---or the trouble you're having is related to details you have not yet revealed.

Comment: @tmyklebu I will try lesser memory and see. I have checked function and gradient calculation, by checking whether it matches with finite difference calculation.